# How to compose multiple unit test result in a single txt file

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qtestlib

I am using QTestLib Library and QTest for running my unit tests. I am working on windows 7 and using Qt 4.8  When I run my test using:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Test gui widgets - 2 Spinboxes and 1 Combobox
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TestSpinBox  testSpinBoxObj;
    TestComboBox testComboBoxObj;

    QTest::qExec(&testComboBoxObj, argc,argv);
    QTest::qExec(&testSpinBoxObj, argc,argv);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output in the console:

```
Starting D:\Projects\Qt Learning\TestGui (1)\TestGui\debug\TestGui.exe...
********* Start testing of TestComboBox *********
Config: Using QTest library 4.8.1, Qt 4.8.1
PASS   : TestComboBox::initTestCase()
PASS   : TestComboBox::testComboBoxStepUp()
PASS   : TestComboBox::testComboBoxStepDown()
PASS   : TestComboBox::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 4 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
********* Finished testing of TestComboBox *********
********* Start testing of TestSpinBox *********
Config: Using QTest library 4.8.1, Qt 4.8.1
PASS   : TestSpinBox::initTestCase()
PASS   : TestSpinBox::testSpinBoxStepUp()
PASS   : TestSpinBox::cleanupTestCase()
Totals: 3 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
********* Finished testing of TestSpinBox *********
D:\Projects\Qt Learning\TestGui (1)\TestGui\debug\TestGui.exe exited with code 0
```

How to get the same in a single text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is -o filename option to specify output file](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html#options). For each test object you can redirect output to own file and later concatenate them together.

```
QList<QObject *> objects;
objects << new TestSpinBox << new TestComboBox;

QString result;
foreach (QObject *o, objects) {
    QTemporaryFile f;
    f.open();
    QStringList args = app.arguments();
    args << "-o" << f.fileName();
    QTest::qExec(o, args);
    result += "\r\n" + f.readAll();
}
qDeleteAll(objects);
```